# Nested optimization leads to conflict with constraints in inner problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nested-function

In  this  nested  optimization  problem  something  is  going  wrong in  the  step  when  I  substitute  `u1op[x_]`  for  `w1`  in  `rfull` .

Can  you  help  me  to  correct  this  error? The  first  lines  are  just  defining  the  functions . **The  error  must  happen   in  Z1.** I  included  Z2  and  Z3  only  to  proof  that  the  error really  happens  because  of  the  above  mentioned  substitution .

```
  Clear["Global`*"]
\[Mu][w1_, w2_, w3_] := Min[w1, w2, w3]
uw[w1_, w2_, w3_] := w1/umax + w2/umax + w3/umax ;
F[x_, w1_, w2_, w3_] := Min[1 - \[Mu][w1, w2, w3]* x, (umin/uw[w1, w2, w3]) - (umin/umax)*\[Mu][w1, w2, w3]*x];
rfull[t_, w1_, w2_, w3_] := NMinimize[{( \[Mu][w1, w2, w3]*y + F[y, w1, w2, w3]*(umax/umin) y )^(-1), 1 <= y <= n - 1 + (umin/umax)}, y][[1]]
t[t1_, t2_, t3_] := t1 + t2 + t3
Fair[x_] = x + t[t1, t2, t3];
t1 = 0.5; t2 = 0.5; t3 = 0.5;

(*Defining the calculation of the wi*)
u1op[x_] := Module[{result}, 
  result = Last@NMinimize[{Max[Abs[u1 - u2], Abs[u1 - u3], Abs[u2 - u3]], 
      u1 + u2 + u3 == Fair[x], u1 >= t1, u2 >= t2, u3 >= t3}, {u1, u2,
       u3}, Method -> {"Automatic", "InitialPoints" -> {{0, 0, 0}}}];
  u1 /. result]
u2op[x_] := Module[{result}, result = Last@NMinimize[{Max[Abs[u1 - u2], Abs[u1 - u3], Abs[u2 - u3]], u1 + u2 + u3 == Fair[x], u1 >= t1, u2 >= t2, u3 >= t3}, {u1, u2, u3}, Method -> {"Automatic", "InitialPoints" -> {{0, 0, 0}}}];
  u2 /. result]
u3op[x_] := Module[{result},  result = 
   Last@NMinimize[{Max[Abs[u1 - u2], Abs[u1 - u3], Abs[u2 - u3]], 
      u1 + u2 + u3 == Fair[x], u1 >= t1, u2 >= t2, u3 >= t3}, {u1, u2,
       u3}, Method -> {"Automatic", "InitialPoints" -> {{0, 0, 0}}}];
  u3 /. result]

(*Defining fixed parameters*)
t1 = 0.1; t2 = 0.1; t3 = 0.1; umax = 1; umin = 0.1; n = 3;
t[t1, t2, t3]
(*Nesting the problems*)
Z1 =
 1 - NMinimize[{(x + 
        t[t1, t2, 
         t3])/((Min[x/rfull[t[t1, t2, t3], u1op[x], u2op[x], u3op[x]],
           n - t[t1, t2, t3]]) + t[t1, t2, t3]), 
     0 <= x <= n - t[t1, t2, t3]}, x][[1]]
Z2 =
 1 - NMinimize[{(x + 
        t[t1, t2, 
         t3])/((Min[x/rfull[t[t1, t2, t3], 0.1, 0.2, 0.3], 
          n - t[t1, t2, t3]]) + t[t1, t2, t3]), 
     0 <= x <= n - t[t1, t2, t3]}, x][[1]]
Z3 = u1op[2]
```

Thank you very much in advance.